# NSScrollView override scroll speed - OSX

Tags: cocoa, webview, scrollview, nsscrollview, smoothing

I have a project which is using a `WebView`, in [Mavericks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks), Safari 7 has really smooth and fast scrolling and I would like to create replicate this for my `webView`.

The following key allows for momentum:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"];
```

However I would like the momentum to carry on for longer or the scrolling to be genuinely faster, is there anyway I can override the speed on the `NSScrollView` within a `WebView`? In the least complicated way if possible?

In iOS you have levels of control using:

```
webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

But I can't find any similar methods for OSX.

Comment: Please can anyone assist?